# MS Access LEFT JOIN SQL-syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error

Read the MS Access [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to learn how to do a LEFT JOIN sql operation. Been staring at my query now for one hour without being able to spot the problem.

```
SELECT gen_id_id 
  FROM ES_issue_table 
       LEFT JOIN __MOTHER_ISSUE_TABLE_6 
          ON ES_issue_table.issue_id = __MOTHER_ISSUE_TABLE_6.issue_id
```

This gives me the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][Drivrutin f?r ODBC Microsoft Access] Syntaxfel i fr?geuttrycket 'ES_issue_table.issue_id = __MOTHER_ISSUE_TABLE_6.issue_id'.
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at daos.MdbDao.testQuery(MdbDao.java:146)
at MdbDaoTest.testingQueries(MdbDaoTest.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Does it help when you state which table `gen_id_id` is coming from? Eg: `ES_issue_table.gen_id_id `

Comment: You should try your SELECT instruction with MS ACCESS query interface or any other query tool. Are the joining fields of the same type and size?

Comment: Odd. Is it just the LEFT JOIN that's giving you gyp? i.e. do `SELECT * FROM ES_issue_table` and `SELECT * FROM __MOTHER_ISSUE_TABLE_6` both work? Can't see anything wrong with what you're doing, based on what you've said, so maybe it's your columns and data types. As @Philippe says, try it in Access to verify the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table name `__MOTHER_ISSUE_TABLE_6` is not a valid table correlation name because of the leading underscore characters. Try an alternative -- preferably shorter! -- table correlation name e.g.

```
SELECT *
  FROM ES_issue_table AS E1 
       LEFT JOIN __MOTHER_ISSUE_TABLE_6 AS M6
          ON E1.issue_id = M6.issue_id;
```

If you are really fond of using your long table names then escape using square brackets i.e.

```
SELECT *
  FROM ES_issue_table 
       LEFT JOIN __MOTHER_ISSUE_TABLE_6 
          ON ES_issue_table.issue_id = [__MOTHER_ISSUE_TABLE_6].issue_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the `issue_id` field in `ES_issue_table` and the `issue_id` field in `__MOTHER_ISSUE_TABLE_6` are the same data type (for example both **Numbers** or both **Text**)